# How to find the amplitude of a complex number $z=-1-\sqrt{3}i$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Find the amplitude of a complex number $z=-1-\sqrt{3}i$.
I got the modulus of $z$ is $2$. After solving that I am getting $\cos(-60^\circ)$ and $\sin(-60^\circ)$.

I don’t have any idea how to solve after that

Comment: The argument (which I am guessing is what you mean by amplitude) of a complex number of the form $r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ is by definition $\theta$.

Comment: Doesn't amplitude mean the same as modulus, in this context?

Comment: I got the modulus of z = 2. I have to find the amplitude means the value of theta

Comment: I don't think that's what *amplitude* means. Maybe you're thinking of *argument*.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a picture!

[image]
Here, $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ denotes de *amplitude* of the complex number $z$, or better said, denotes the *argument* of $z$. Then, we see that
$$\operatorname{Arg}(z) = 180^\circ + \theta$$
and, with a little bit of trigonometry, $\theta$ satisfies that 
$$\tan \theta = \frac{-\sqrt 3}{-1} = \sqrt 3$$
then, $\theta = \arctan(\sqrt 3) = 60^\circ$ and then
$$\operatorname{Arg}(z) = 180^\circ + 60^\circ = 240^\circ.$$

Comment: Is 240 degree the answer?

Comment: Formally, the answer will be $-\pi/3$ since $\operatorname{Arg}(z)\in [-\pi,\pi]$ for every $z\in \Bbb C$, but, the idea with the draw is still correct.