# Find the amplitude of complex number $z= 2\sqrt{2}\,i - 2\sqrt{3}$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Find the amplitude (the angle) of this complex number

$$z= 2\sqrt{2}\,i - 2\sqrt{3}$$

I am getting that the modulus is $2\sqrt{5}$. After that I am getting $\cos -\sqrt{3}/{\sqrt{5}}$  and $\sin\sqrt{2}/\sqrt{5}$. How to find the answer?

---

See also my previous question, [How to find the amplitude of a complex number $z=-1-\sqrt{3}i$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3360558/409).

Comment: Do you mean $$2\sqrt{2i-2\sqrt{3}}$$?

Comment: Please use MathJax, the same way it was used in previous questions you have posted.

Comment: I don’t know how to use MathJax. 2sqrt2i and 2sqrt 3 is seperate.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Is it $ 2\sqrt{2}i\,-\,2\sqrt{3}$

Comment: Yes this is right

Comment: If above writen by me is what you were asking then amplitude is $ tan\alpha = -\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} $ $\\$. $\alpha =\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}})+2nπ $  where n is an integrr

Comment: It should be $ \alpha=-\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}})+2nπ $ , where n is an integer

Comment: And $ - \tan^{-1}(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}) $ be then in second qudrant

Comment: Can anyone please help me for this problem?

Comment: @RahulRoyChowdhury: I have formatted your question using MathJax. Please double-check that it shows what you intend. ... Also, since you asked [a very-similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3360558/409) previously, perhaps you can say something here about why the answers you've received there have not been sufficient. (Please [edit the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3360659/edit) to add more thoughts. Comments are easily overlooked.)

Comment: I found the modulus of z. But the thing is I don’t know how to find the amplitude in this case

Comment: What do you call the *amplitude* of a complex number?

Comment: To find the angle. The value of theta

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The angle you seek is usually called the [argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Modulus_and_argument) of a complex number.

You have correctly found the modulus.  The complex number $z = 2\sqrt{2}i - 2\sqrt{3} = 2\sqrt{3} - 2\sqrt{2}i$ is represented by the point $(-2\sqrt{3}, 2\sqrt{2})$ of the complex plane, as shown below.

[image: polar_angle_of_complex_number]

Since the angle $\theta$ is in the second quadrant and
\begin{align*}
\arcsin x: & [-1, 1] \to \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]\\
\arccos x: & [-1, 1] \to [0, \pi]\\
\arctan x: & (-\infty, \infty) \to \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)
\end{align*}
we can most easily find the angle by finding the arccosine of the angle.  Hence,
$$\theta = \arccos\left(\frac{-2\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{5}}\right) = \arccos\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{5}}\right)$$

**Note:**  Cosine and Sine take an angle as their argument.  You should have written
\begin{align*}
\cos\theta & = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
\sin\theta & = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{5}}
\end{align*}